# How to create Json from items in List in VStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have following structure

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var usedWord = [String]()
    @State private var  rootWord = ""
    @State private var newWord = ""

    var manager = HttpRequest()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                TextField("Enter your symptom", text: $newWord, onCommit: addNewWord)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .autocapitalization(.none )
                    .padding()
                List {
                    ForEach(usedWord, id: \.self){
                    Text($0)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
                }

                Button("Get diagnose"){
                    // here we plac logic of sending request to API server

                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle(rootWord)
        }
    }

    func addNewWord() {
        let answer = newWord.lowercased( ).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        guard answer.count > 0 else {
            return
        }

        // extra validation to come
        usedWord.insert(answer, at: 0)
        newWord = ""
    }

     func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        self.usedWord.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

It's a list of text items in it. In Button("Get diagnose") i would like to iterate over List and create Json object to sent it to API server. Json structure looks something like {'1': 'pain in chest', '2': 'headache'}. I have a request function, but i don't know how to create Json

Comment: The question is incorrect, you should ask how to create json from a string array, `usedWord`, because you use your data source and not some UI components for that. `let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(usedWord)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the `list`. You should iterate over the list's data like:

```
Button("Get diagnose"){
    // here we plac logic of sending request to API server
    for word in self.usedWord.enumerated() {
       print(word.offset, ":", word.element)
    }
}
```

I don't know how you need the JSON but, You can build a `dictionary` from that like:

```
let dictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(self.usedWord.indices, self.usedWord))
```

And the `JSONData` like:

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
```

Comment: This is perfect! But can self.usedWord.indices is integer and i get 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary'. How can i convert self.usedWord.indices to String? I tried String(self.usedWord.indices) but it doesn't work

Comment: i figure out  let converted = dictionary.map{[String($0) : String($1)]}
Thank you for your answer